# How can I get Youtube comments using Jquery and Youtube api V3?

Tags: jquery, youtube, tampermonkey, youtube-data-api

So, I saw a lot of question in this subject, but all answers is start with old gdata url, which is dosen't work anymore.
I would like to get comments for every video, if I click a (appended) button on this page:
https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions
Obviously this is a tampermonkey script.
My finish is, I whanna get a little sneek peak from the content, so I can decid I whana click for the youtube link or not.
Maybe I plan reply function for the comments, but this just a future plan.
What I have now:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         hovercards for youtube
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant        none
// @require     https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
  //'use strict';

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("a.yt-uix-tile-link,.yt-ui-ellipsis-2k").on("mouseover",function() {
         //Replace video block start    
$(function() {
    $('a.yt-uix-tile-link,.yt-ui-ellipsis-2k').each(function() {
        var yt_url = this.href,
            yt_id = yt_url.split('?v=')[1],
            yt_title = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith('<div class="youtube-box" style="background-image:url(https://img.youtube.com/vi/' + yt_id + '/0.jpg);"><span class="youtube-title">' + yt_title + '</span><span class="youtube-bar"><span class="yt-bar-left"></span><span class="yt-bar-right"></span></span> </div>');
        $("div.youtube-box").on("mouseover",function() {
            $(this).replaceWith('<iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="youtube-frame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + yt_id + '?autoplay=1"></iframe>');
        });
    });
});
  //Replace video block end
});

});
```

And I would like to separete that code isent  work at this time, so i would like to add this on working format of course:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("'a.yt-uix-tile-link,.yt-ui-ellipsis-2k").append("<input type='button' value='Give me my comments' class='button'>");
jQuery(".button").on("click",function() {
jQuery.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?id=yVqreR8VXwQ&key=YOURAPIKEY&part=snippet',function(data){
//Replace the YOURAPI key section for your key
 if (typeof(data.items[0]) != "undefined") {
     console.log('video exists ' + data.items[0].snippet.comment);
     $(".result").append( data.items[0].snippet.comment);
   } else {
     console.log('video not exists');
     jQuery("result").append("Nope, we don't get any data");
 }   
});
});
});
```

When I looked in to the broweser this URL with my api key:
'`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?id=yVqreR8VXwQ&key=YOURAPIKEY&part=snippet`'
I get this result:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#commentListResponse",
 "etag": "\"kiOs9cZLH2FUp6r6KJ8eyq_LIOk/pGLBhpjR05yQoJV31WoAx2PEFVw\"",
 "items": []
}
```

And I don't understand why, why I dosen't get any items?
The url looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

May be This will work

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId={YOUR_Video_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You can see the required information here.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads#methods

Answer (score 1):

```
 GET  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=AIzaSyDDBk8tAkod1VRRNyFZF09fgQyMpnSe5HI&textFormat=plainText&part=snippet&videoId=kffacxfA7G4&maxResults=50
```

You can try this it's working fine for me.

Comment: Hmm looks fine based your answer I maked this:
http://jsfiddle.net/bTLX8/15/
The only problem is we have not only one video but many,many more, and we need to chancge the video id string to actual video id.
how this possoble?